# TokuDB fails to load in MariaDB, even when transparent hugepages are disabled

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, upgrade, mariadb, tokudb

Earlier, I upgraded my website server to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I had a very nice setup with MariaDB and the TokuDB engine. However, the setup was kind of messed up when TokuDB refused to load properly, causing WordPress to display the install page because it could not read the database tables! Agh! (Hopefully they are still there...)

I [disabled transparent hugepages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages) (because they were enabled after the upgrade), but TokuDB still refuses to load, even when I followed the [directions on the MariaDB website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-enable-tokudb-in-mariadb/):

```
MariaDB [(none)]> install soname 'ha_tokudb';
ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'TokuDB'; Plugin initialization function failed.
```

What else could be causing TokuDB to not load?

**UPDATE:** I have fixed the issue. You can read about it here: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6165

Comment: Did you follow the directions here? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-enable-tokudb-in-mariadb/

Comment: @slm Yes, I did.